# Angular 2.0 - How to import a child module?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been following the AngularJs 2.0 tutorials, and I'm stuck trying to import a child component. I'm new to angular in general so this may be a very amateur mistake.

I have this module which was working till I added the NavigationComponent directive and reference:

```
/// <reference path="Navigation.ts" />
/// <reference path="../angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import { NavigationComponent } from './Navigation'

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'roadmap'
})
@View({
  templateUrl : 'roadmap.html',
  directives: [NavigationComponent, NgFor]
})
// Component controller
export class Roadmap {

  herName: string;
  content: string
  names: Array<string>;

  constructor() {

    this.herName = 'Jessica';
    this.content = "test content";
    this.names = ["Aarav", "Martín", "Shannon", "Ariana", "Kai"];

  }

  addName(name: string){
    this.names.push(name);
  }

  doneTyping($event) {
    if($event.which === 13) {
      this.addName($event.target.value);
      $event.target.value = null;
    }
  }
}

bootstrap(Roadmap)
```

And I have the NavigationComponent defined as such :

```
/// <reference path="../angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'navigation'
})
@View({
  template: `<h1> tester </h1>`
})

export class NavigationComponent {

  message: string;

  constructor() {
    this.message = "I'm the navigation";
  }

}
```

I can't get the import statement correct. I have both the Roadmap.ts and the NavigationComponent.ts in the same folder.

There errors I'm seeing aren't communicating anything useful :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Any advice ?

Comment: `System is not defined` is referring to systemjs. Most likely its referring to the line where you call `System.import`. Can you show the html where you call that?

Comment: The cdn was down. My code worked as soon as I got home yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using scripts from internet in your `index.html` and have problem to access them, becouse I have same problem now. I suggest replace it with local files.

In this solution I'm using jspm package manager (you can install it via `npm install -g jspm`).

In your project root folder run command:

```
jspm init
```

You can leave default configuration of jspm - just press Enter for every line. Now run:

```
jspm install traceur-runtime
```

You should have all required files in `jspm_packages` folder. Now replace this (or similar) lines from your `index.html`

```
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
```

with this:

```
<script src="jspm_packages/github/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.88/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
```

EDIT: It looks like everything is OK now - files are online again. If problem will be back in future remember to check version of files from jspm and replace outdated ones from this answer.

Comment: I'll check this when I get home. I am indeed using the cdn versions of those javscript files.